# GetDeclaredSymbol is null

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to parse a solution and I am trying to call

```
var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
```

The variable node is set to a public method but GetDeclaredSymbol always returns null. I set diagnostics and there are no errors found only a few warnings.

Any idea why I am getting null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using InvocationExpressionSyntax instead of MethodDeclarationSyntax . I got a node that returned a symbol.

```
  var nodes = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                    .Where(x =>
                    {
                        return x.Identifier.Value == methodName;
                    });
```